# Android widget not showing up on the emulator screen

Tags: android, widget, emulation

I have added some widgets on activity_main.xml, a layout file for main.java in android. When I ran the program on  emulator, the last widget is missing in the emulator screen. What will be the reason? How to rectify it?
Here by I am giving below the code for activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg1"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cmplnlogo"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo" />
<EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/signupUserHint"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FF00FF"
        android:id="@+id/textViewEmailValidator" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/signupPwd"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextPwd" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/signupCfmPwd"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextConfirmPwd" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FF00FF"
            android:id="@+id/textViewPwdValidator" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/signInHint"
            android:onClick="GoToLogin"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/textViewSignin" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
            android:text="@string/SignUp"
            android:onClick="SignUp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSignUp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/service_terms"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/textViewServiceTerms" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show it to us SIr, so we can identify it

Comment: No Problem I had the solved the issue by adding scrollview.

Comment: wow.. okay.. help others by posting an answer..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem mentioned in the above question by adding scrollview widget. I added the scrollview widget in the layout file for which all widgets are not appearing on the emulator. Remember scrollview only suppors only one direct file. 
I had many layouts inside the layout file that enclosed different widgets. I enclosed all the layouts with in one layout. And then, enclosed that layout with scrollview. I am giving the snippet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/scroll">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/username"
            android:id="@+id/registerUserName"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/enterRegisterUserName"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</Scrollview>
```